# Discord bot with async error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

When ever I run the code I get an error with `async`, I have imported `asyncio` to attempt to fix this but the errors keep flooding in

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

bot = command.Bot(command_prefix="=")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Bot Onine!")
    print ("Hello I Am " + bot.user.name)
    print ("My ID Is " + bot.user.id)
```

The error I get:

> ```
> async def on_ready():
>     ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Please if anyone knows a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `async` keyword you need python 3.5 or above. If you're using python 3.4 or below you can't use `async`.

the alternative is to decorate the method with `coroutine`. This code

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    ...
```

Becomes:

```
@bot.event
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_ready():
    ....
```

Since discord events already need the `bot.event` decorator, `discord.py` api provides the `async_event` decorator to do both the coroutine and the event decoration in a single call, so you can also write it like this:

```
@bot.async_event
def on_ready():
    ....
```

In the same vein, you can't use `await` either, so you must use `yield from` instead.

```
await bot.say('Some response')
```

becomes

```
yield from bot.say('Some response')
```